# Reading from a .dat file Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, readfile

I have a `.dat` file which looks something like the below....

```
#| step | Channel| Mode | Duration|Freq.| Amplitude | Phase| 
    0       1       AWG     Pi/2    100     2           1               
    1       1       SIN^2           100     1           1   
    2       1       SIN^2           200     0.5         1   
    3       1       REC     50      100     1           1               
    100     0       REC    Pi/2     150     1           1
```

I had created a data frame and I wanted to read extract data from the data frame but I have an error

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DataFrame
```

My code is below here,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
path = "updated.dat"
datContent = [i.strip().split() for i in open(path).readlines()]
#print(datContent)
column_names = datContent.pop(0)
print(column_names)

df = pd.DataFrame(datContent)
print(df)
extract_column = df.iloc[:,2]


with open (df, 'r') as openfile :
    for line in openfile:
        for column_search in line:
            column_search = df.iloc[:,2]
            if "REC" in column_search:
                print ("Rec found")
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: You're calling `open(df)`, i.e. with a DataFrame but that's not how the [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function is used.

Comment: Might be helpful to include the entire error message, including the traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your post does not have any clear question, I have to guess based on your code. I am assuming that what you want to get is to **find all rows in DataFrame where column *Mode* contains value *REC***.

Based on that, I prepared a small, self contained example that works on your data.

In your situation, the only line that you should use is the last one. Assuming that your DataFrame is created and filled correctly, your code below `print(df)` can be exchanged by this single line.

I would really recommend you reading the official documentation about indexing and selecting data from DataFrames. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""
no;step;Channel;Mode;Duration;Freq.;Amplitude;Phase
;0;1;AWG;Pi/2;100;2;1
;1;1;SIN^2;;100;1;1
;2;1;SIN^2;;200;0.5;1
;3;1;REC;50;100;1;1
;100;0;REC;Pi/2;150;1;1
""")
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=";")


df.loc[df.loc[:, 'Mode'] == "REC", :]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, apologies for the unclear question, as you said im trying to extract the rows of REC if the column is REC, how should I do if that .dat contains lot of data? Also I donot wish to convert it into csv or any other format

Comment: Error you provided appears to be caused by the line `with open (df, 'r') as openfile`. This means that the code you wrote to read the `.dat` file is not generating any error. Thus, I am assuming that variable `df` contains all the data from the file. If all those assumptions are true, that single line will show you all rows from the `.dat` file that contain value `REC` in column `MODE`. You can safely ignore all previous lines from my example, they are just there for making it easier to reproduce your problem.

Comment: What do you mean? To see what `df` contains, just do `print(df)`. To extract only a part of data, where is `REC` in column `MODE` you just need to use the last line of my example. `df.loc[df.loc[:, 'Mode'] == "REC", :]`. If you want to extract it to a separate variable, just assign it to something else `df_extracted = df.loc[df.loc[:, 'Mode'] == "REC", :]`.

Looking once again in your code, it appears that you do not keep names of the columns. You will need to adjust my code to work properly with that. But this you can easily do based on the official documentation.